# How do i make input's line be below the printed line?

Tags: python

This is what i have:

```
choice = int(input("Choose an action")) - 1
```

In the console it appears like this:

```
Choose an action(The user input goes here)
```

What i want is:

```
Choose an action
(the user input goes here)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either print the message, which will automatically add a newline:

```
print("Choose an action")
choice = int(input()) - 1
```

Or include a newline (`\n`) manually at the end of the input message:

```
choice = int(input("Choose an action\n")) - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

just do :

```
print("Choose an action")
choice = int(input()) - 1
```